# On nodeJs, can SQL Server return joined tables an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

My table data is:

```
                 **partMaster**

         id        partNumber      rev     
    |------------|------------|------------|
    |    01      | assy1      |    C       |
    |------------|------------|------------|
    |    02      | comp1      |    A       |
    |------------|------------|------------|
    |    03      | comp2      |    F       |
    |------------|------------|------------|

                    **boms**

         id        partId         itemId        qty     
    |------------|------------|------------|------------|
    |    01      | 01         |    02      |    5       |
    |------------|------------|------------|------------|
    |    02      | 01         |    03      |    11      |
    |------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

My query is

```
SELECT *
FROM partMaster
left join boms on boms.partId = partMaster.id
WHERE (partMaster.id = '01')
```

This returns (along with other things) a recordset, such as,

```
[
    {
        id:[01,01],
        partNumber:'ASSY1'
        rev:'C',
        itemId:'02',
        qty:5
    }
,
   {
        id:[01,01],
        partNumber:'ASSY1'
        rev:'C',
        itemId:'03',
        qty:11
    }
]
```

This to me is very confusing. I would prefer something like,

```
[{
id:01,
partNumber:'assy1',
rev:'c'
boms:[{id:01,partId:01,itemId:02,qty:5},{id:02,partId:01,itemId:03,qty:11}] //Left Joined Table 
}]
```

Is this possible with SQL Server (or any NodeJs Compatible SQL database)?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You can use an ORM, which should normalize tabular data into the structure you're requesting.  I like Formn (https://benbotto.github.io/doc/formn/5.x.x/).  TypeORM (https://typeorm.io/#/) is probably the most popular ORM for Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2016 or newer you can use `FOR JSON`.

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.partNumber,
    p.rev,
    (SELECT b.id, b.partId, b.itemId, b.qty FOR JSON PATH) as boms
FROM partMaster p
left join boms b on b.partId = p.id
WHERE (p.id = '01');
```

Side note: it is best practice to never use `SELECT *` in your code.  Always return only what you need in your resultset.  Table schemas can change over time which makes the results of `SELECT *` also vary.

Comment: I wonder why this question isn't asked more often. Lots of data in RDBMS tables would require data returned with this shape.